# Unable to update apps: On-Prem SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, iis

I am unable to update our apps on an on-prem SharePoint site.

When I click the update link on our SharePoint app from the site contents page, I am taken to the storefront.aspx page where I can click "Get it" to update the app. When I click "Get it", a dialog box (appinv.aspx) opens up with a message saying that the ad domain refused to connect.

[image]

When inspect the page, an error is showing up in the console: "Refused to display 'http://domain.ad' in a frame because it set multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('DENY, SAMEORIGIN'). Falling back to 'deny'".

[image]

When I access the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools, I see that there are 2 X-FRAME-OPTIONS being set in the HTTP Response Headers section. There is an X-FRAME-OPTIONS with a value of "DENY" and another X-FRAME-OPTIONS with a value of "SAMEORIGIN". I looked in IIS and found no X-FRAME-OPTIONS with a value of "DENY" and there does not seem to be any duplicate X-FRAME-OPTIONS headers to be found anywhere on the server. I am unsure where this is being set and I'm unable to locate it.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this before? If so, how can I resolve? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remedy this, make sure the SharePoint Server has been updated with this or later:

```
SharePoint Server 2019: September 14, 2021 (KB5002018)
SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016: September 14, 2021 (KB5002020)
SharePoint Foundation 2013: September 14, 2021 (KB5002024)
```

Log onto the SharePoint server and open a Windows Powershell command window as Administrator. Run the following commands:

```
add-pssnapin *
$f=get-spfarm
$f.AddGenericAllowedListValue("AllowIframeAppAuthorizePageDomains","<domain name>")
$f.update()
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/appinv-aspx-page-can-t-be-added-to-iframe-kb5005546-5c944028-f072-43f5-8f12-c03ba501acec